# Видеоплеер на реакте, с возможностью создавать главы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, видео, mediaplayer, youtube-api

Я ищу видеоплеер для реакта, в котором будет возможность разделять видео на главы (примерно так, как это реализовано на youtube). Как я понял, в [компоненте ютуба](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) такой возможности нет.

Выглядеть это должно примерно вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желательно, что бы источником видео могли быть как внешние так и локальные файлы
Так же, желательно иметь возможность кастомизации, например, задавать разным главам разный цвет

Подскажите кто знает какие-нибудь готовые решения ?

Comment: сейчас заминусят наверное, тебе в чатик надо какой-то пойти в телеге @it_chats

Comment: Тут все что есть https://morioh.com/p/e974b7e53384